# Weird MSCV error on Compiler Explorer for a peculiar combination of Win line break and split view

Tags: c++, visual-c++, line-breaks, range-v3, compiler-explorer

Take this relatively small sample code which uses Range-v3 do define a function that returns a `std::vector<std::string>` splitting the input `std::string` on any of `\n` or `\r\n` line breaks.¹

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;
using namespace std::literals;

std::vector<std::string> splitOSAgnostic(const std::string& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for_each(
        str | split("\r\n"s) | transform(split("\n"s)) | join,
        [&result](auto snippet_view) {
            auto documentSnippet = snippet_view | to<std::string>;
            result.push_back(documentSnippet);
        });
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto res = splitOSAgnostic("a = 1;\nb = 2;\r\nc = 3;\n"s);
    assert(res[0] == "a = 1;"s);           // ^^---- if I remove this,
    assert(res[1] == "b = 2;"s);           // everything is fine
    assert(res[2] == "c = 3;"s);
}
```

[On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j5orhf5Y3) I get the following error:

```
example.cpp
<source> : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-explorer-compiler2023110-17256-1pb5efl.2aus\output.s.obj': Permission denied
Compiler returned: 1
```

What am I facing?

Needless to say that Clang and GCC are happy with the code.

---

(¹) I haven't used regexes for other reasons, but the question is not related to that.

Comment: You've made example overcomplicated. [Here is minimal version](https://godbolt.org/z/MP8se1bzT). Note dropping `#include <cassert>` also fixes issue ;? Dropping range3 library also fixes problem.

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent result. So looks like problem is on godbolt configuration.

Comment: The example at your link has no issue?

Comment: I did more experiments and got inconsistent results. For same code different only by empty line I got error you've mentioned, success or `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file` so this is not code issue, but some problem with MSVC setup on godbolt. Looks like some race condition on resources. Empty lines were used to avoid use of godbolt cache.

Comment: @MarekR, I see... a race condition. Pretty much like Godbolt is running and MSVC can't keep up with him :D

Comment: Recently there was some issue with MSVC and recent versions of it has been removed. So probably after restoring those some new problems has pop up.